# Подключитесь к сети, вставьте SIM-карту(,) или купите пакет и воспользуйтесь eSIM

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, предлоги

***Подключитесь к сети, вставьте SIM-карту(,) или купите пакет и воспользуйтесь eSIM.***

Здесь "купите пакет и воспользуйтесь eSIM" логически связаны, это как одно действие, то есть воспользоваться eSIM можно, только купив пакет.

Сомневаюсь, нужна ли запятая перед "или". И еще не могу разобраться, почему именно так.

Comment: Какие места вызывают сомнения? Просто в голову не приходит, на основании чего можно убрать имеющуюся запятую или где тут можно влепить еще.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, нужна ли запятая перед "или". И еще не могу разобраться, почему именно так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая тут не нужна, да и, судя по всему, невозможна.

Мне кажется, вопрос надуман. Запятая перед союзом "или" может появиться только если:
1) она закрывает предыдущее обособление или последующую пояснительную конструкцию
2) либо этот союз оформляет сложносочиненное предложение (ССП).

https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/kogda-pered-soyuzom-ili-stavitsya-zapyataya.html
(источник не академичен, но хорош простотой объяснений).

Первый мотив тут исключается полностью, что до второго, то ССП из двух повелительных предложений - нонсенс. Грамматика в принципе такое допускает, но по факту и здравому смыслу такие конструкции трактуются как два однородных сказуемых. В этом случае запятая перед "или" невозможна.

Что до ваших сомнений, правильно ли поймут фразу, то я не испытываю по этому поводу большого беспокойства. По контексту понятно, что приобретение пакета предопределяет возможность использования eSIM - и наоборот.